# moz-document url-prefix not working in developer and nightly

Tags: css, firefox, cross-browser

i have this css:

```
#data_submit_ensg:hover {width: 200px;}

@-moz-document url-prefix() {
    #data_submit_ensg:hover {width: 295px;}
}
```

it works in Firefox standard edition 
but doesn't work when using developer edition or nightly ?